# How to use mode in multimodal set in QlikView expression?

Tags: qlikview

`Mode` function in QlikView will return the mode element in array, only if there is only one. If there is more than one it returns null.

I need to return list of Modes in someway in a expression.

How can I return the list of modes in a multimodal set like:

1
3
3
5
5
7
9

I would to return 3, 5. So I can take Min, or Max, or Avg..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to read up on Multimodals, so correct me if I'm wrong. This expression returns the highest of the two values that has the highest number of occurances (right?):

```
Max( 
 Aggr ( 
  if (count( Num)>=Max(total Aggr(count( Num),Num)) ,Num),
  Num)
)
```

I use the Aggr function to create the list to pick from. So change the first Max to whatever you want to pick.

Comment: I've tried to use this expression in a graph filtered by another column... So I didn't use the `total`, is there a problem with this? Because my result get a slight difference to the database.. (Got 19.94 instead of 19.44)

Comment: The total makes sure you calculate the highest values across the whole dimension. So you should use it.